# What is the cardinality of the set of all functions mapping $\{\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5}, \sqrt{7}\}$ into the rational numbers?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Let $T = \{\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5},\sqrt{7}\}$ and $\mathcal{S}$ the set of all functions that maps $T$ into $\mathbb{Q}.$ What is the cardinality of $\mathcal{S}$?

So far I've been messing with the idea that we can take the subset $T_0\subset T$ of functions that square an element of $T$ and adds any other string of rational numbers to it. For example $f(\sqrt{2})=(\sqrt{2})^2+a$ where $a \in \mathbb{Q}.$ Since $|T_0|$ is countable and infinite $|T_0|=\aleph_0.$

I'm not really sure if this is going to get me anywhere.

Comment: It is same as the cardinality of $\mathbb{Q}^{4}$, which is countable.

Comment: The particular values of your set are not important.  Only that it has four elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you answer the question of the cardinality of the set of all functions from $\{ 1 \}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$?  I hope so, it's obviously the same as $\mathbb{Q}$ since any such function can be specified by a single value from $\mathbb{Q}$.

Now, how about the cardinality of the set of all functions from $\{ 1, 2 \}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$?  Well, any such function can be specified by two values from $\mathbb{Q}$ so its cardinality is the same as $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q} = \mathbb{Q}^2$.  Do you know the cardinality of this set?

Let's jump a step to the set of functions from $\{1, 2, 3, 4 \}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$.  As Seewoo says, this has cardinality $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q} = \mathbb{Q}^4$.  If you figured that $\mathbb{Q}^2$ is countable then you should see that this is as well.

Now your set: $\{\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5}, \sqrt{7}\}$.  Well there is a very simple bijection between it and my set $\{1, 2, 3, 4 \}$ which can be easily used to associate the maps from my set to $\mathbb{Q}$ with those from your set to $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: I absolutely understand this. Thank you so much. I got so caught up in the values of the set and not how many elements are in the set. This is a new level of abstraction for me compared to what I've been exposed to so far at the undergraduate level.

Comment: @TrevorMason.  I expect that was the intention of whoever wrote the question.  How about the set $\{ 0, 1, e, i, \pi \}$?

Comment: This should have cardinality $\mathbb{Q}^5?$

Comment: Yes, but what is that?

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}= \aleph_0?$

Comment: Yes.  You have to work quite hard to get a bigger set.  I used to enjoy teaching this.  At first, the students expected that $\mathbb{Q}$ was bigger than $\mathbb {Z}$ which was bigger that $\mathbb{N}$.  After learning that these and many others were the same size, they started to think that all infinite sets were the same size.  Then I hit them with $\mathbb{R}$.